# How to return selected items from checkboxlist control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to return in a string the selected items from a dynamically bound checkbox list control with no luck. I'm hoping someone can help. In my code behind file I am conencting to a class called users and building a datatable. I then bind the data table to the cblist control

```
        private void populateUserList() //called on page load
    {

            SubmitOptions mySubmission = new SubmitOptions(juris, rptType, tmplName);

            if (mySubmission.Users.Count == 0)
            {
                lbl_juris.Visible = false;
                cb_selectUser.Visible = false;
                lbl_AlertMsg.Visible = true;
                btnSelect.Visible = false;
                lbl_AlertMsg.Text = "No supervisors listed for jursidiction: " + juris.ToString();
            }
            else
            {

                dt.Columns.Add("Users");
                for (int i = 0; i < mySubmission.Users.Count(); i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Users"] = mySubmission.Users[i];
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                cb_selectUser.DataSource = dt;
                cb_selectUser.DataBind();
            }

     }
```

Within the main aspx file I have the control defined as:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cb_selectUser"
       Width="400px" 
       Height="100%"
       AutoPostBack="false"  
       runat="server"  
       CellPadding="2"  
       CellSpacing="5"
       DataTextField="Users" 
       DataValueField="Users"
        >
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I have tried the following code where i itterate through the list but this only seems to work if I hard code values into the Checkboxt list as listitems.

```
 protected void btn_returnUserList(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cb_selectUser.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cb_selectUser.Items[i].Selected)
            {

                selectedUsers += cb_selectUser.Items[i].Text;
            }
        }
```

The list populates fine and all I want to do is return in a string all selected users from the checkbox list control.

As I said if I hard code the item values into the control the above code works and I can see the selected items in the string however removing the itemslist tags and switching over to a binding nothign happens. The above method counts the entire number of returns but nothing selected is ever returned.

Any tips or suggestions as to what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is complete code of page working exactly as you want it. just add a CheckboxList to form name it to list1, add a button name it to btn and add a label and name it lbl.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Users");

                const string str = "User {0}";
                for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
                {
                    //var r = dt.NewRow();
                    //r.ItemArray=new object[]{string.Format(str,i)};
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {string.Format(str, i)});
                }
                list1.DataSource = dt;
                list1.DataTextField = "Users";
                list1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var s = list1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                   .Where(item => item.Selected)
                   .Aggregate("", (current, item) => current + (item.Text + ", "));
            lbl.Text = s.TrimEnd(new[] {',', ' '});
        }
```

Comment: When testing this I the entire list is bing returned in the List. In your example you return 10 items in the llist but if only one checkbox item is selected the string ( s) still displays all 10 items.

Comment: sorry dear @randyc. I've updated the `Linq` expression with `Where` clause to get only selected items.

Comment: Thanks so much. My Linq is weak at best and while understanding what you were doing I was unsure where to make a change. Thank you again for your help. This is a great and efficient solution.

Comment: Here is foreach for you: `foreach(ListItem item in list1.Items) {       if(item.Selected){ s+=item.Text+", ";}}`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure populateUserList() is only being called once? (i.e. not on postback as well).  If it gets called twice the selected items collection will be blank.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
    populateUserList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, Yes I am testing for postback in the page load as well as within the method itself. This method is only being called once.

Answer (score 2):

1- Download Jquery.json.js and add it to your view as refrence:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
2- I've added a ".cssMyClass" to all checkboxlist items so I grab the values by their css class: 


 <script type="text/javascript" >
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#btnSubmit").click(sendValues);
         });

         function populateValues()
         {
             var data = new Array();
             $('.myCssClas').each(function () {
                 if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                     var x = $(this).attr("value");
                     data.push(x);
                 }
             }); 

             return data;
         }

         function sendValues() {
             var data = populateValues();
                   $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Save")',
                       data: $.json.encode(data),
                       dataType: 'json',
                       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                       success: function () { alert("1"); }
                   });

           } 



     </script>
```

3- As you can see I've added all selected values to an Array and I've passed it to "Save" action of "Home" controller by ajax
4- in Controller you can receive the values by adding an array as argument:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(int[] val)
        {
```

I've searched too much but apparently this is the only solution. Please let me know if you find a better solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
   string skills="";
   for(int i=0;i<chkboxlist.Items.Count;i++)
   {
       if(chkboxlist.Items[i].Selected)
       {
           skills=skills+chkboxlist.Items[i].Text+",";
       }
   }
   skills = skills.Remove(skills.Length-1);
   lblResult.Text = skills.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the sender to retrieve your selected items and see if you get the same result?

```
protected void btn_returnUserList(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList cbl = sender as CheckBoxList;
    if (sender == null) {
        throw new Exception("Sender is not a CheckBoxList");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cbl.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cbl.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            //  Also, set a breakpoint here... are you hitting this line?
            selectedUsers += cbl.Items[i].Text;
        }
    }
```

Also, test to see if you're getting into the block for selected items... are they registering as selected, but not getting the text back?  Or do the items not show up as selected in the first place?

Comment: James, I did test this and it was running to the break point however I think there is something in the way the items are being created dynamically. When I test this it continues to return a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your checkboxlist has databound before trying to retrieve values from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:-

```
    foreach (ListItem li in cb_selectUser.Items)

   {
       //Your Code
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem. You have to bind the `CheckBoxList` as follows:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
   //Bind your checkboxlist
}
```