# how to get selected items count in asp:checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i have a checkboxlist control

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkselectedItems" Font-Size="12px" runat="server"> 
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and i created listitems on it dynamically.If i checked more than one item from the checkbox list, How i get the selected item count using asp.net

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770874/how-to-return-selected-items-from-checkboxlist-control-in-asp-net , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395454/how-to-loop-thru-a-checkboxlist-and-to-find-whats-checked-and-not-checked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

```
int numSelected = 0;
foreach (ListItem li in chkselectedItems.Items)
{
if (li.Selected)
{
numSelected = numSelected + 1;
}
}
Response.Write("Total Number Of CheckBoxes Selected:");
Response.Write(numSelected);
```

**pre**

```
public string[] CheckboxListSelections(System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList list)
{
 ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
 for(int counter = 0; counter < list.Items.Count; counter++)
 {
  if(list.Items[counter].Selected)
  {
   values.Add(list.Items[counter].Value);
  }    
 }
 return (String[]) values.ToArray( typeof( string ) );
}
```

Comment: is there any possibility to get exact count?

Comment: @pranay..can u post ur previous answer please?

Answer (score 41):

Use this single line of code:

```
int selectedCount = chkselectedItems.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Count(li => li.Selected);
```

Comment: Really awsome...Thanks a lot :) ;)

Answer (score 4):

We will iterate through the checkboxlist and use a counter variable for counting selected items. For every item in checkboxlist we will add 1 to counter variable selCount if item is checked

```
int selCount = 0;   

for(int i= 0; i< chklst.Items.Count; i++) 
  if(chklst.Items[i].Selected)
      selCount++;
```

// Now selCount will contain the count of selected items

Answer (score 0):

**Using Linq**

```
 var count=  chkmenuitemdef.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(c => c.Selected).Count();
```