# How to count the checkboxes in a asp.net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFilter" runat="server">
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb01" checked="checked" />
        <label for="cb01">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb02" checked="checked" />
        <label for="cb02">None</label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

C#:

```
foreach (Control item in this.form1.Controls)
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox _cbx = item as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if (_cbx != null)
    {
        if (_cbx.Checked)
        {
            //Do something: 
            Response.Write(_cbx.Name + " was checked.<br />");
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting a `null` value for the `_cbx` variable.

How can I update it so I am able to get the ID of all the `checked` input type checkboxes.

I tried this answer: [Count the number of TextBoxes and CheckBoxes in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712051/count-the-number-of-textboxes-and-checkboxes-in-a-form) but didn't work for me either.

Comment: You should look into `runat=server`

Comment: Tried that already but let me "retry" it again :)

Comment: I shouldn't have to use runat="server" because I am looking for HtmlInputCheckBox... unless I am wrong?

Comment: None of solution worked except Lokki, however there were some limitation. I will +1 but won't accept the answer as it didn't completely resolve my issue. I manually checked for each CheckBox... for now. I will post a solution if I come across or can figure out what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: this could help [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1929531.aspx?How+to+Count+Checked+CheckBoxes+in+the+page+) ,and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460378/how-to-get-selected-items-count-in-aspcheckboxlist) is if you want to do it in a checkbox list way hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the DOM if you want to use `<input type="checkbox">`.
I advise you to use `<asp:CheckBox>` instead of `<input type="checkbox">`. Then you can access your controls from c#

In your lookup: 

`var _cbx = item as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;`
You can get all checkboxes without looping through all controls. 
Use LINQ:

`this.form1.Controls.Where(c=>c.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))`

Comment: Does it matter that it's inside an UpdatePanel?

Comment: input is a client-side control and it's supposed to be used on the client side.
asp:CheckBox - is a server-side control and it can be used on server side.

Comment: Oh, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Comment: Ok Thanks. It's a webform

Comment: I can access it like this: `var y = cb01.Checked;` no issue but if I have 20 checkboxes that's a lot of manual work...

Comment: The link worked so far, let me do some more testing. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your checkboxes do not run at server. As such they have no control "assigned" in the code-behind. Try adding the attribute runat="server" to your checkboxes. Just like you have in your panel.

Comment: Nope, it's coming up as `null` still :/

Comment: I shouldn't have to use runat="server" because I am looking for HtmlInputCheckBox... unless I am wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. I didn't read correctly. For it to work you should use asp:checkbox and look for those in your code-behind

Comment: Still having same issue

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.All)
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox _cbx = element as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if (_cbx != null)
    {
        if (_cbx.Checked)
        {
            //Do something: 
            Response.Write(_cbx.Name + " was checked.<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `webBrowser1`? What's that?

Comment: The code example requires that your application contains a WebBrowser control named WebBrowser1.  Find the example in MSDN help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.all(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't unfortunately.

Comment: What is your page name?? change webBrowser with ur page name . It should work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add `runat="server"` or change them to `asp:CheckBox` controls.

But the reason you can't find them if you add them is because they are in another control. So look for them in `pnlFilter`.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFilter" runat="server">
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb01" checked="checked" runat="server" />
        <label for="cb01">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb02" checked="checked" runat="server" />
        <label for="cb02">None</label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind

```
foreach (Control item in pnlFilter.Controls)
{
    HtmlInputCheckBox _cbx = item as HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if (_cbx != null)
    {
        if (_cbx.Checked)
        {
            //Do something: 
            Response.Write(_cbx.Name + " was checked.<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is a combination of all the suggested changes.
Make the checkboxes runat server as to have 'm available server-side:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFilter" runat="server">
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb01" checked="checked" runat="server" />
        <label for="cb01">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb02" checked="checked" runat="server" />
        <label for="cb02">None</label>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

And as suggested interate the (sub)controls of the panel:

```
foreach (Control item in this.pnlFilter.Controls)
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox _cbx = item as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if (_cbx != null)
    {
        if (_cbx.Checked)
        {
            //Do something: 
            Response.Write(_cbx.Name + " was checked.<br />");
        }
    }

}
```

Or if you changed the checkboxes to `asp:Checkbox` then the type would be `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox`

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to access front-end stuff by front-end process.

For example, collect checked checkbox ids you need by JQuery and save them inside `HiddenField` then get it back-end by request.

Instance

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFilter" runat="server">
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb01" checked="checked" />
        <label for="cb01">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dvFilter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb02" checked="checked" />
        <label for="cb02">None</label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdfIds" name="hdfIds" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

JQuery part(link JQuery & json2 lib first)

```
function recoverCbxStatus() {
    if (hdfIds.value) {
        var ids = JSON.parse(hdfIds.value);
        ids.forEach(function (id) {
            $('#' + id).prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
}

function refreshIds() {
    var ids = [];
    $('input:checkbox[id^="cb"]:checked').each(function () {
        ids.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    hdfIds.value = JSON.stringify(ids);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    recoverCbxStatus();
    refreshIds();
});

$('input:checkbox[id^="cb"]').change(function () {
    refreshIds();
});
```

Back-end(Nuget Json.NET)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string idsJson = Request["hdfIds"];
    List<string> ids;
    if (idsJson != null)
    {
        ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(idsJson);
        Response.Write("count: " + ids.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView. And code side do this-

```
for (int i = 0; i < **yourGridViewId** .Rows.Count; i++)
    {

CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox)**yourGridViewId** .Rows[i].FindControl(" **yourCheckboxId**"));
....

}
```